# MVC: store input value as variable in controller or query view when I need the value?

Tags: python, model-view-controller

I am building a graphic python application with some sort of MVC (as far as I can tell) pattern implemented.

I have a slider which represents a value. Now, I have two options how to access this value.

- I could have a variable in my controller which holds the value of the slider. Whenever the slider is updated in the view, the view transmits the value to the controller through an event.
- I could have a function in the controller which, whenever called for, asks the slider in the view what its current value is.

The second option seems more dynamic, but if I'm making plenty of calls it seems more efficient to have the value stored.

Is the question basically of how often and in what way I expect the value to change, or is there some generally accepted best practice in this situation?